# MySQL Connector MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Instalei o MySQL Connector e local obtive sucesso, consegui efetuar a conexão e até mesmo realizar meu `Migration`.

Porém, após dar *Publish* no meu projeto e subir no FTP, estou me deparando com o seguinte erro:

> Cannot perform CAS Asserts in Security Transparent methods

Lendo mais sobre, entendi que é um erro de "permissão" por conta do complemento não fazer parte do pacote.

Adicionei em meu app.config a seguinte linha, como foi indicado em um outro site:

```
<loadFromRemoteSources enabled="true" />
```

Porém, não obtive sucesso. Como poderia estar tratando isso?

Comment: Qual servidor você hospedou sua aplicação !?

Comment: Você subiu todas as referencias ? na solução clicou com o botão direito e ("Copy Local = true") ?

Comment: @Maria tentei via godaddy e obtive o pior resultado, não conseguir rodar nem uma versão estática de aplicação. Via locaweb obtive o erro relatado.

Comment: @thiago.adriano26 Sim sim, fiz isso.

Comment: você já tentou isso ? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/40138/publicar-aplica%c3%a7%c3%a3o-com-entity-framework-mysql?answertab=votes#tab-top