# Publicar aplicação com Entity Framework + Mysql

Tags: mysql, entity-framework

Estou usando o `Entity Framework` para `Mysql`.

Instalei o `.Net Connector`, e o `MySQL.Data.Entities`.

Localmente está funcionando normalmente. Porém quando vou subir para o `LocaWeb`, não vai.

Aparece o seguinte erro:

> Cannot perform CAS Asserts in Security Transparent methods
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot perform
>   CAS Asserts in Security Transparent methods
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [InvalidOperationException: Cannot perform CAS Asserts in Security
>   Transparent methods]
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory..ctor() +24
>   MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration..ctor() +73
>
> [TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of
>   an invocation.]    System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType
>   type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached,

Meu Web.config:

```
 <connectionStrings>
        <add name="BancoDados" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=xxxx; port=3306; Initial Catalog=bancoMySQL; uid=usuarioMySQL; pwd=qwe123qwe;" />
      </connectionStrings>
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6, Version=6.8.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"></provider>
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
```

Comecei a fazer algumas pesquisas e cheguei até uma referência da `LocaWeb`:
[LocaWeb](http://wiki.locaweb.com.br/pt-br/Erros_mais_frequentes_no_Asp.Net) no tópico:

> MySqlConnector / Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data
>   Provider. It may not be installed

Então fazendo o que fala no tópico, adicionei

E

```
  <system.data>
        <DbProviderFactories>
            <clear />
            <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.8.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
        </DbProviderFactories>
    </system.data>
```

Porém não surtiu efeito.

Até achei uma página na internet, porém não entendi muito bem o procedimento que falava, e acho que é o mesmo que recomenda a LocaWeb, mas vou deixar aqui o [LINK](http://rbrundritt.wordpress.com/2010/09/18/mysql-net-4-entity-framework-and-medium-trust-hosting-environments/)

Comment: Locaweb? Vou rezar pela sua alma.

Comment: Você fez `Copy Local = True` nas DLLs antes da publicação?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez, em TODAS DLLs ou só as quais são referentes a Mysql?

Comment: O ideal era todas porque a Locaweb é chata pra tudo.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez, ainda mesmo erro!!!

Comment: Não conheço muito a Locaweb, mas há a possibilidade de registrar Assemblies no GAC da máquina?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez, não... Até onde tenho conhecimento não, a unica coisa que consigo fazer é upload de arquivos... hahaha!

Comment: Bom, é o seguinte: esse erro quer dizer que o Assembly não pode ser inteiramente executado por restrições de segurança. Acho que neste caso o melhor é entrar em contato com o suporte da Locaweb pra pedir uma orientação diretamente pra eles. Não dá pra responder porque pode ser várias coisas, e não tem uma solução única.

Comment: Realmente pessoal, na Locaweb só funciona com a versão MySqlConnector abaixo do 6.3.

Answer (score 1):

Ja sofri muito com isso!

Na locaweb, só funciona com a versão no MySqlConnector abaixo do 6.3 ou 5.3, não me lembro direito!

Basta você baixar o connector antigo, substituir as dll, e alterar as versões deles no web.config! É o único jeito!

Na época, passei tanta raiva, que eu andei migrando alguns sites para o Hotel da Web que ja tem incluso o banco SQL Server!

Comment: Tentei baixar o connector 5.3 só que ele vem apenas como executável... Como eu consigo as dll dele? E a PublicKey no webconfig, permanece a mesma?

Comment: Provavelmente você encontrará no C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\

Basta adicionar na referencia do projeto, acho que as publickeys são as mesmas

Comment: Hoje, a versão atual da Locaweb é a 5.1

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia amigo,

passei por esse problema e resolvi com o pessoal da locaweb, apenas acrescentando a linha includesecurityasserts=true entre os parametros do webconfig na connection string, simples.